# SQL query to join 2 tables even though column to join doesn't match

Tags: sql

Write a SQL query for the following case:

I have 2 tables containing timestamp data. Table 1 and Table 2 has following columns:
`timestamp, query_time`

If I took out the top 5 most recent timestamp rows from each table and then sort then by timestamp, I wanted to join these rows such that most recent timestamp row from table 1 matches with most recent timestamp row from table 2 and so on.

Example:

```
Table 1 has:

timestamp, query_time
1, 1
2, 4
3, 6
4, 8
5, 10

Table 2 has
 
timestamp, query_time
10, 10
20, 200
30, 300
40, 400
50, 500

I want to join these 2 tables as follows:

t1_timestamp, t1_query_time, t2_timestamp, t2_query_time
1, 1, 10, 10
2, 4, 20, 200
3, 6, 30, 300
4, 8, 40, 400
5, 10, 50, 500
```

Comment: Why is `1, 1` joined with `10, 10` and not with `20, 200`?

Comment: @TheImpaler because like it's written in the question "*wanted to join these rows such that most recent timestamp row from table 1 matches with most recent timestamp row from table 2*"

Answer (score 2):

You don't specify RDBMS, but in most RDBMS's this can be accomplished with the `ROW_NUMBER()` window function to derive a row number, upon which you can join:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
   (SELECT timestamp, query_time, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY timestamp ASC) as row_num FROM table1) t1 
   INNER JOIN (SELECT timestamp, query_time, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY timestamp ASC) as row_num FROM table2) t2
       ON t1.row_num = t2.row_num
```

Older versions of mysql and mariadb would look different, AccessDB would look different, and Oracle could be done in an easier way with its `ROWNUM` psuedocolumn.

Answer (score 0):

This works on sql server:

```
declare @table1 table (ts timestamp, qt float);
declare @table2 table (ts timestamp, qt float);

insert into @table1 (qt) values (rand());WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:00:10';
insert into @table1 (qt) values (rand());WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:00:10';
insert into @table1 (qt) values (rand());WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:00:10';
insert into @table1 (qt) values (rand());WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:00:10';
insert into @table1 (qt) values (rand());WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:00:10';

insert into @table2 (qt) values (rand());WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:00:10';
insert into @table2 (qt) values (rand());WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:00:10';
insert into @table2 (qt) values (rand());WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:00:10';
insert into @table2 (qt) values (rand());WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:00:10';
insert into @table2 (qt) values (rand());WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:00:10';

with
 t1 as (select rank() over (order by ts desc) id, * from @table1 where ts in (select top 5 ts from @table1 order by ts desc)) 
,t2 as (select rank() over (order by ts desc) id, * from @table2 where ts in (select top 5 ts from @table2 order by ts desc))
select t1.ts t1_timestamp,t1.qt t1_query_time,t2.ts t2_timestamp,t2.qt t2_query_time
from t1 join t2 on t1.id=t2.id
;
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to join two tables without a common column is the "from" clause as below:

SELECT t1.timestamp, t1.query_time, t2.timestamp, t2.query_time
FROM Table1 t1, Table2 t2;

or you can use a cross-join:

SELECT t1.timestamp, t1.query_time, t2.timestamp, t2.query_time
FROM Table1 t1
CROSS JOIN Table2 t2;

I give this above solution because you did not mention any common column for both tables in your question. if there are common column exits then the syntax is as follows:

Select t1.timestamp, t1.query_time, t2.timestamp, t2.query_time
From Table1 t1
JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id;